# Is the point-oscillation of a (discontinuous) linear functional continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

I have a Banach space $X$ and a linear functional $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

The oscillation of $f$ at a point $x$ is defined as $$\omega_f(x) : \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} [ \sup_{y,z \in B_\delta(x)}|f(y)-f(z)| \ ]$$
My question is: can we prove that the function $\omega_f(x): X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}_+$ is continuous?
Thanks

Comment: You mean your $f$ is everywhere defined and linear but discontinuous? That is a very pathological object that can only be [constructed with axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#Role_of_the_axiom_of_choice). And you can not expect any sort of regularity out of it.

Comment: To expand on Conifold’s comment: linear functionals are either continuous, or unbounded on any open subset, so your oscillation is either zero everywhere, or infinity everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,x'\in X$.  Then since $f$ is linear, the values it takes on $B_\delta(x')$ are just the same as the values it takes on $B_\delta(x)$ but translated by $f(x')-f(x)$.  It follows immediately that $\omega_f(x)=\omega_f(x')$, so $\omega_f$ is constant.

(In fact, as mentioned in the comments, any discontinuous linear functional is unbounded so it takes unbounded values on any ball, so $\omega_f$ is always $\infty$ unless $f$ is continuous so it is always $0$.)